# WebSocket server just receives "G" from handshake header using ssl

Tags: c#, ssl, websocket, certificate

I'm just beginning to understand how to get a WebSocket Server (C#) to use SSL.
I've already written a server, but without SSL with NetworkStream instead of SslStream and stuff.

I copied this server from the internet and rewrote something:

```
class Program
{
    static X509Certificate2 serverCertificate = null;

    public static void RunServer(string certificate)
    {
        serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2();
        serverCertificate.Import(certificate, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1111);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client to connect...");

            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            ProcessClient(client);
        }
    }
    static void ProcessClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(), false);
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Default, true);

            sslStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
            sslStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client message...");
            string messageData = ReadMessage(sslStream);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", messageData);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
    static string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[570];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;

        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
        decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
        messageData.Append(chars);

        return messageData.ToString();
    }
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunServer("server.pfx");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And this is my client (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Websocket</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:1111");

        ws.onopen = function() {
            console.log("Connected!");
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {

        };

        ws.onclose = function() {

        };
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The problem is: The server doesn't get the complete HTTP header. The only thing in messageData in the ReadMessage method is "G" (without quotation marks).
I don't get an error message or anything except that the handshake failed (Google Chrome). Also buffer[0] has the value 71(ASCII for G), the other 569 have the value 0. (The length of the buffer is 570, by the way, because client.Available in a while loop outputs 570 throughout.)

I use the same client on the server without SSL, only difference: Instead of wss:// I use ws://

Can anyone help me with this problem? I don't quite understand it.

By the way, I created the certificate via PowerShell:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "localhost" -FriendlyName "WebSocketCert" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Just change line in ProcessClient from:
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Default, true);
to:
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);